# Google Embeded maps won't work with infra-red touch frame

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3, touch

I'm trying to use Google Maps (JS APIv3) in Chrome, in a kiosk mode, intending to use it with and infra-red touch frame. IR touch frame in a HID-mode (emulating not a mouse, but rather a touch device) works perfectly with [maps.google.com](http://maps.google.com), allowing to pan map with a finger, but won't allow it on an embedded map.

I assume that Google uses some sort of additional library for touch events, but looking into source code haven't given me any hints.

Anyway, is it possible to enable panning in an embedded google map for a generic touch device?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well.. even they have document on this [control option](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#ControlOptions), they don't seems to provided ways to enable the touch to pan event....

One work around might be to set to user-agent as chrome on Android.